# When a change of variable results in equal limits of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Here is something that's been bugging me for a while. Say we want to find $$I = \displaystyle\int\nolimits_{a}^{b}f(g(t))g'(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$

If we substitute $x = g(t)$, then $$I = \displaystyle\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$ But what do we do in the case where $g(a) = g(b)$? How do we interpret that?

For example, if $x = \sin{t}$, $a = 0$, and $b = \pi$, then $g(a) = \sin(0) = \sin(\pi) = g(b)$. It would appear that the integral would be zero, but I find it isn't.

What to do when a given substitution makes both limits the same?

Comment: If $g(t)=\sin\;t$, then your integral is antisymmetric about $t=\pi/2$, so...

Comment: @J. M. So my integral would be $2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(x)\;{dx}$?

Comment: *anti*-symmetric, my friend. antisymmetric.

Comment: "what to do when a given substitution makes both limits the the same." - you'd then want to check if your integrand is antisymmetric about the midpoint of the interval you're integrating on.

Comment: @ J. M. I think that's what I was after, thank you! Could you say bit more about that though? If it's symmetric about the mid point, then $I = 2\int_{0}^{m}f(x)\;{dx}$ where m = [g(b)-g(a)]/2; but if it's antisymmetric about the midpoint, then it's zero.  Is that correct?

Comment: On the nose, except the integral in the symmetric case should be over the interval $[g(a),m]$. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I've to figure out a way to accept a comment! :)

Comment: Alright, give me a few; what I've written isn't elaborate enough as a full answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, when you find that some substitution you've done has made the lower and upper limits identical, it's always a good idea to check if your integrand is symmetric or antisymmetric about the midpoint of the integration interval. For the specific case of

$$\int_0^\pi f(\sin(t))\cos(t)\,\mathrm dt$$

instead of doing the substitution $u=\sin\,t$ which sets both limits of integration identical, you might instead try the simpler substitution $t=v+\frac{\pi}{2}$, which turns your integral into

$$\int_{0-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}} f\left(\sin\left(v+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)\cos\left(v+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\,\mathrm dv$$

or

$$-\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f\left(\cos\,v\right)\sin\,v\,\mathrm dv$$

Now, noting that $f\left(\cos\,v\right)\sin\,v$ is odd ($f\left(\cos(-v)\right)\sin(-v)=-f\left(\cos v\right)\sin v$), the integral can be split like so

$$-\left(\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^0 f\left(\cos\,v\right)\sin\,v\,\mathrm dv+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f\left(\cos\,v\right)\sin\,v\,\mathrm dv\right)$$

and then we can do the following:

$$-\left(\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^0 f\left(\cos(-v)\right)(-\sin(-v))\,\mathrm dv+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f\left(\cos\,v\right)\sin\,v\,\mathrm dv\right)$$

$$-\left(-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f\left(\cos\,v\right)\sin\,v\,\mathrm dv+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} f\left(\cos\,v\right)\sin\,v\,\mathrm dv\right)$$

and you can now see that the integral is supposed to be zero, which is consistent with the result from the substitution that made both integration limits the same.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't said what $f$ is. Once you fill in **all** the parts of the first integral $\int_a^b f(g(t))g'(t)dt$, you can check that the change of variable formula is true - for example, $$\int_0^\pi \sin(t)\cos(t)dt=0=\int_0^0 xdx$$

Comment: Chronoles, take, for example, $\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^2{x}\sin{x}\;{dx}$

Comment: That's not of the form $f(g(t))g^\prime(t)$... anyway, your example is *symmetric* about $x=\pi/2$.

Comment: @Student: You should keep your $x$'s and $t$'s separate. I assume you mean to ask about the case of $f(x)=x^2$, $g(t)=-\cos(t)$ (so that $g'(t)=\sin(t)$). But in this case, $g(\pi)=1\neq -1=g(0)$, so we would not expect the integral to equal 0.

Comment: Oh, dear! Apologies for sloppiness. I was having problem with in general when a given substitution makes the limits the same, but I didn't realise that the form I've given was so limiting.